# breakpoint in histogram using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x= seg.mean)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.6, colour="black", fill="white") 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(seg.mean, na.rm=T)),  
    color="red", linetype="dashed", size=0.5)
```

How can i increase the break points of x axis, for eg range of x  axis form -5 to 5, with an interval of 0.5

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use scale_x_continuous: `+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-5,5,by=0.5))`

Comment: @Heroka..if i want to plot with only values from -2 to 2 on x axis and  break  by 0.01, i tried scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-2,2,by=0.01)). But the plot is getting crowded.

Comment: I know. Is there any alternative way way to plot ?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Why do you want so many tickmarks?

Comment: Heroka,  i tried it in this way. hist(res1$seg.mean, xlim=c(-2, 2), breaks=5000). I want to know the breakpoint by looking at the distribution

Comment: @Kryo, It sounds like you want to increase the number of histogram bins? In ggplot2 this is done with `geom_histogram(binwidth=0.0008)`. `binwidth` has the same units as your data, so -2 - 2 = 4; 4 / 5000 = 0.0008.